# How do I tail AWS CloudWatch Log Stream logs?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I'm using the CloudWatch logs service to store logs coming from containerized applications, in the other hand I developed a NodeJS script using the AWS SDK to get those logs.

I'm looking for a way to live tail the logs, not only to send requests and get logs but also to open a stream and get new logs.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via the AWS command line, here's an example:

```
$ aws logs tail /my/log/group/name --follow
```

References:

- https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/logs/tail.html

Comment: is there a way to do that (tail) using aws sdk nodejs.